# Python : Checking if a string does not exist in a list of lists

Tags: python, python-2.7, conditional-statements

I have a simple code that generates a list of lists and populates it with string "null", however when I try to check if "null" doesn't exist in the entire list of lists, it doesn't give me the result I'm expecting

```
lst = [ ['null']*4 for n in xrange(2) ]
print lst
if ('null' not in lst):
    print "testing"
```

This code always prints "testing" and I don't know why.
Your explanation is appreciated
Thanks

Comment: The string `'null'` is not in the list. It's in a list that's inside the list.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your list `lst` is not a list of strings but a list of lists of strings.
You might try:

```
if any('null' in lst2 for lst2 in lst):
```

as your test: that is, return `True` if there is a string `'null'` in any of the sublists of your main list, `lst`.

Answer (score 0):

flatten the list and then do a "is not in" check on the flattened list:

```
flattened = [x for x in sublist for sublist in lst]
if "null" not in flattened:
    print("testing")
```

Comment: Patience is for you to have. Don't click "post answer" until you have an answer.

Comment: Nice save though.

Comment: I'll do my best in the future